# CDNS Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, fonts, webfonts

hello all i am using cdns to host my images on another server what issue i am getting with my font icons are

```
 Font from origin 'http://www.domain.com' has been blocked from loading by 
 Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
 header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
 'http://control.domin2.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

please suggest me smething i am lost 
also i am on genex not on apache so i can not use htaccess file.

after searching i got this only but valid for apache

```
  # BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS

     AddType font/ttf .ttf
      AddType font/eot .eot
      AddType font/otf .otf
     AddType font/woff .woff

 <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   </IfModule>
 </FilesMatch>

 # END REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
```

please help me its important i need to solve this issue .

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent nginx config would be:

```
location ~* \.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

You may also go through [this page](https://michielkalkman.com/snippets/nginx-cors-open-configuration.html) for open CORS configuration.